# Hover a DIV class and 5 other DIV class change transparent

Tags: jquery, css, hover

i have been struggling with this for a few days. I have a total of 6 DIV class in my main page and i would like to do a simple effect where when one of the DIV class is being hover, the other 5 DIV class will become slight transparent.

I have tried a few methods but it dont seem to be working. Can anyone help me with this? 
thanks alot!!

Comment: could you show your tried but not working code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".test").hover(function() {
    $(".test").not($(this)).css({"opacity" : 0.1});
},
 function() {
     $(".test").css({"opacity" : 1});
});
```

See: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agZMc/)

Comment: Tried the above code but it still not working :( . can you tell me where my mistake is??
http://jsfiddle.net/CnUKW/9/

Comment: your html does not contain any class named "test" which you are using in jquery as selector.. do you mean like this:: http://jsfiddle.net/CnUKW/12/

Comment: oh! something like that but i would only like to have one of the box to be the darker shade and the rest transparent.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CnUKW/24/ its working here now but its not working on my browser..why is that so? i inserted jquery inside the HEAD section. am i doing it right?

Comment: yea, wrap the code in $(document).ready(function() { .... your code here.. }); and it should work, like here:: http://jsfiddle.net/CnUKW/26/

Comment: <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".test").hover(function() {
        $(".test").not($(this)).css({
            "opacity": 0.1
        });
    }, function() {
        $(".test").css({
            "opacity": 1
        });
    });
});​ 
</script>

i inserted this inside the HEAD section but its still not working in my browser...

Comment: do you see any errors..! and did you change class "test" to appropriate one you are using in your html code...

Comment: yes i did.i used the exact same codes as from jsfiddle and i did not see any errors..

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I missunderstood your question the first time. Improved answer.

I don't know your exact html setup but something like this should do the trick:

```
jQuery(".myDivClass").mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery(this).siblings().css({"opacity": 0.7});
}).mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery(this).siblings().css({"opacity": 1});
});​
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xbRwv/1/)

Comment: thanks alot for your help! still trying hard to work things out :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like;

```
$(".mydiv").mouseenter(function() {
  var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
$("div").not(this).css("background-color", "#7EA9D5");
  }).mouseleave(function() {
$(".mydiv").css("background-color", "#06C");
  });
```

You may use a single class and different IDs. Give a value to the transparent color (or may use the CSS `opacity`) ***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/uGBa4/1/)*** is a working Live demo. (I used color here)

Comment: You do know you can just do `not(this)` ?

Comment: thanks alot for your help :) ! still trying to work it out though.

Answer (score 0):

You should obtain better performances with CSS only : [Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/VeWM3/)

```css
.container > div {
    background: #0FF;
}
.container:hover > div {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.container:hover > div:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Comment: thanks alot for you help! tried all method but its still not working so guessed the problem lies with my existing code.